# Alternative to PanoramaGL

Tags: android, panoramas

I am using the PanoramaGL to render some Spherical images in my App.

My images are more than 3000 pixels larger. I tried using PLSpherical2Panorama of PanoramaGL that supports 2048x2048 but the quality is not good.(I resized my images)

Then I split my panoramas into cubic images, each face got 1527x1527px. I edited the panoramaGL library to support cubic images of 2048x2048px(originally it supported only 1024x1024). The quality was better than spherical2, but yet was not what I expect, and the performance got horrible too.

A friend is making the same app for iOS and he used that library: https://bitbucket.org/javieralonso/japanoview

The result was perfect.

So, my question is: anyone knows any android library that renders spherical or cubic images and have the hotspot feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found PanoDroid(http://www.frank-durr.de/panodroid.html) that is a library to download Flickr images and transform them into a panorama image.

I had to change a lot of things in the library and just use her kernel, but the result was very good. Panodroid do a great job with big images.

But unfortunatelly Panodroid don't implement Hotspots. I will have to add this feature into the library.

--EDIT--

Frank Durr had transformed PanoDroid into a open source project.

Here is the link to his explanations: http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=26

And here is the link for the OpenPanoDroid: https://github.com/duerrfk/OpenPanodroid

Comment: Hi, can you post the code of library which you have modified to support hotspots?

Comment: Sorry, but I was not able to implement HotSpots in Panodroid and make them clickable. I switched back to panoramaGL.

Comment: the above link was broken :-(

Comment: @jonathanrz Hi.. Thanks for update. Above library is only for viewing Panorama images. Do you have any idea about creating Panorama images? is there any library for Android? please help... Thanks

Comment: @GopalRao the camera of CyanogenMod is open source and I believe that records panorama images.

Comment: I'm trying to use lib OpenPanodroid, but the problem is that i can't zoom and dezoom on image loaded, how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: @tamtoum1987 I don't know in OpenPanodroid, but try to change do PanoramaGL v2, it is very complete :)

Comment: jonathanrz ok i will try PanoramaGL :)

Comment: I try it, it work bether, but PanoramaGL only supports images with sizes at power of two e.g. 2048x1024, 1024x1024, 1024x512, 512x512, 512x256, 256x256, 256x128.

How can i extend PanoramaGL to another format.? (I dont know if it's possible)

Comment: @tamtoum1987 What size do you need?

Comment: i don't know yet the patron tell me juste to add possibility to show image panorama, so i'm not sur he gonna like this constraint of size, but i'm gonna change dimension to 2048x1024 or 1024x1024  if size image is big, i think programmatically i can do that

i have another problem, how can i change zoom limit on PanoramaGL, it is possible ?

Comment: @tamtoum1987 Yes, you should constraint the size to prevent performance issues, I already have used with 6x 1024x1024 and the performance was just regular. About the zoom I don't know, but I believe yes. I have already disabled the zoom. If you can't change de zoom, you can look to the code and implement, I have already changed myself the code and it it now so difficult.

Answer (score 3):

You can also now use Google VR's `VrPanoramaView`

https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/pano/VrPanoramaView